# SSL handshake reuse in Azure Webapp

Tags: .net, azure, ssl, nginx, web-applications

we're having the problem with SSL handshakes takes too much traffic and since we have the same clients using our site, we're looking for a way to store the handshake between requests. We're using Azure webapps, that is a .NET application hosted on Azure as a webapp.

Two solutions has been looked at:
1. Increase the length of a TCP session with the http keep alive header.
2. Use SSL session redemption/reuse.

For 1:
The maximum number of connections could be an issue here. The Traffic Manager should support 500k connections
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#traffic-manager-limits

However I'm not sure that Azure webapps are using the Traffic Manager?

What I did find was a list of limits for the azure webapps:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

And if I read that correct, the maximum is a bit above 8000 connections per node and the max number of nodes is 10. So that would give us 80 000 connections but that also includes outbound connections to for example tableStorage and blobStorage

For 2:
What we can find, this is supported in windows 2012 server as well as in apache and nginx. However Azure webapps and neither of  the load balancers found in Azure seems to support this (correct?). The only way to achieve this would be to setup a virtual machine with a loadbalancer on (for example nginx) that we will support ourselfs?

Our questions is:
1. What is the recommended way of prevent SSL handshakes to be made on every connection with azure webapps?
2. Is there any errors or comments on our reasoning above?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I'm not sure that Azure webapps are using the Traffic Manager?

Azure also can use the Traffic Manger to load balance, it works at the DNS level, but it is not the default load balancer for WebApp.

> However Azure webapps and neither of the load balancers found in Azure seems to support this (correct?).

According to Azure WebApp Architecture, it uses Azure load balancer and Application Gateway to load balance. More information about Azure load balancer and Application Gateway please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction#what-is-application-gateway). So, we no need to setup a virtual machine with a load balancer.

[image]

> What is the recommended way of prevent SSL handshakes to be made on every connection with azure webapps?

Every first connection requires full handshake but subsequent can reuse session ticket (ID), we can set **ARR Affinity** **on** in the Azure portal, then a client establishes a session with an instance and it will keep talking to the same instance until his session has expired.

[image]

Comment: since the SSL session stops at Application Gateway, how will APR on affect this?

Comment: In the Azure WebApp Architecture, ARR stands for **Application Request Routing** IIS Extension to distribute your connecting users between your active instances. ARR forwards the request to the selected web instances. More information about ARR please refer to the [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/disabling-arrs-instance-affinity-in-windows-azure-web-sites/)